# If A positive definite then $\lvert\det(A)| \leq \prod_{i=1}^n \Vert a_{i}\Vert$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

I've asked a similar problem earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3693000/if-a-positive-definite-then-deta-leq-prod-i-1n-a-i-i) and I was told the same is true for $\lvert\det(A)| \leq \prod_{i=1}^n \Vert a_{i}\Vert$

with $\Vert a_{i,i}\Vert$ being the norm induced by the Euclidean inner product so that $\Vert a_{i}\Vert = \sqrt {a_i \overline{a_i}}$

Moreover, $a_i$ is the i-th column of the pos. def. Matrix $A \in \mathbb{C^{n\times n}}$.

Like in my other question I've tried to work with the Cholesky-decomposition because $\prod_{i=1}^n \Vert a_{i}\Vert$ is basically the same operation as $\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,i}$ with the difference, that the first product square-roots all elements.

Sadly, my attempt failed because it seems like $\det(A)$ is actually greater than the product.

Can anyone help me finding a good proof?

Comment: Actually, the formula holds for **any** matrix $A$.

Comment: Oh. How so? I've looked at what $A^*A$ tells me but I don't really get the concept.

Comment: I will write an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'd very appreciate that :-)

Comment: @Quotenbanane See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2301769/81360)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit more delicate. On the other hand more is true.

> For details you may have a look at:
>
> S. Afriat, *Orthogonal and oblique projectors and the characteristics of pairs of vector spaces*, Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. **53** (1957), 800-816.

I will sum it up (since it would be impossible to give all the details):

The volume ${\rm vol}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ determined by the $n$ vectors $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ on the columns of $A$ satisfies
$$
{\rm vol}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\|a_1\|{\rm vol}(a_2,\ldots,a_n)\sin\theta_1,
$$
where $\theta_1$ is the angle between $a_1$ and the $(n-1)$-dimensional space determined by $a_2,\ldots,a_n$ (details in the paper above, too lengthy for a reply). Now you iterate this procedure to obtain
$$
\lvert\det A\rvert={\rm vol}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\|a_i\|\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\sin\theta_i\le\prod_{i=1}^n\|a_i\|,
$$
where $\theta_i$ is the angle between $a_i$ and the space determined by $a_{i+1},\ldots,a_n$.

*PS. Recall that the volume ${\rm vol}(a_i,\ldots,a_n)$ is defined by $${\rm vol}(a_i,\ldots,a_n)=\sqrt{\det ({A_i}^*A_i)},$$ where $A_i$ is the matrix with columns $a_i,\ldots,a_n$.*

Comment: Thanks :-) I'll need some time to review that, especially since i never heard about "vol". I'd have hoped that I could use the result of my other question but that's fine too.

Comment: I added the definition at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Note that this result is often referred to as [Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality).